# Would like help finding resources to generate 3d metaballs using opengl

Tags: opengl, visualization, marching-cubes

I'm looking to work with OpenGl and C++ to generate a procedural real-time metaball animation.

Can anyone suggest a good resource/tutorial for generating metaballs, and/or implementing the marching cube algorithm.

I've spent a fair amount of time googling but having never done anything more complicated than basic GLSL shaders/basic procedural terrain generation/simple particle generation with OpenGL, I'm finding it hard to sort the wheat from the chaff.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Cuda or OpenCL might be better suited for this type of thing.

Comment: @up, negative- I'm pretty sure I've seen a DX10 geometry shader demo with metaball animation. Should certainly be doable on OpenGL/GLSL.

Answer (score 1):

The NVIDIA [CG Isosurface demo](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10.5/Samples/cg_isosurf.zip) might help you out. It includes a metaball implementation.